# Как отправить MediaGroup с фото(url, не файлы) используя requests

Tags: python, telegram-bot, requests, telegram

Как используя только библиотеку `requests` отправить медиа группу с картинками, именно `url`, а не файлы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# токен полученный в ботфазере
token: str = ...

def send_media_group(chat_id, images: list[str], caption: str = None):
    SEND_MEDIA_GROUP = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMediaGroup'
    media = []
    for photo in images:
        media.append(dict(type='photo', media=photo))

    if media:
        media[0]['caption'] = caption

    data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'media': json.dumps(media, ensure_ascii=False),
            'reply_to_message_id': reply_to_message_id}
    return requests.post(SEND_MEDIA_GROUP, data=data)
```